# Catch Exception and prevent it from propogating to parent scope in Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

**Background:** I am fetching data from Bluetooth and after every packet is received it is processed. What I am trying to do is to start timeout when data processing finishes and stop the timer when a new packet is received.

Tried creating a timeout logic using `Flow`. I created a short snippet to test if it works:

```
class ExceptionPropagationTest {
  @Test
  fun test()= runBlocking {
      println(get(coroutineContext))
  }
  
  suspend fun get(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext) = withContext(coroutineContext) {
    try {
      enableDataTransferTimeout()
      delay(3000)
      "Result"
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
      println("Exception caught ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
      "No Result"
    }
  }

  private fun CoroutineScope.enableDataTransferTimeout() {
    flowOf("1").onEach {
      delay(500)
      doSomething()
      throw IllegalStateException()
    }.launchIn(this)
  }

  private suspend fun doSomething(){
      // Do some suspending work
  }
}
```

Above code first prints:

> Exception caught [CURRENT_TIME]

Then logs exceptions stack trace and crashes:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
> com.app.ExceptionPropagationTest$enableDataTransferTimeout$1.invokeSuspend(ExceptionPropagationTest.kt:49)
> (Coroutine boundary)    at
> com.app.ExceptionPropagationTest$test$1.invokeSuspend(ExceptionPropagationTest.kt:32)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

**Question:** Is there any way to catch the exception and return value without propagating the exception to parent scope?

If it is not possible with flow any other solution or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html

Comment: Is `enableDataTransferTimeout` standing for something else? As it is, it seems very over-convoluted to create a Flow of a single item and immediately collect it all within the same function. Is there any reason you can't use [`withTimeout`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html) for your purposes?

Comment: @Tenfour04 This is a simplified version of an actual implementation. `withTimeout` is suspending function but in my case, `enableDataTransferTimeout` should be "ticking" asynchronously. To give a brief info: I am fetching data from Bluetooth and after every packet is received it is processed. What I am trying to do is to start timeout when data processing finishes and stop the timer when a new packet is received. The reason I can't use `withTimeout` is that I don't know how log will it take to process the data

Comment: @BoristheSpider It is still propagating exception to the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `catch` method. [Docs here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html)

```kotlin
flowOf("1")
    .map { 
         delay(500)
         doSomething()
         throw IllegalStateException()
    }
    .catch { ... } // catches exceptions in map or other operands you applied
    .collect()
```

Comment: `collect` doesn't fit my use case as it is suspending. `enableDataTransferTimeout` is an asynchronous function with `Unit` return type and it shouldn't block the flow. Let's say, I have caught the exception in the `catch {...}` what will be the next step? My `get` function needs to return a value when an exception happens how will I return a value from here?

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at  [https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html)

Comment: Unfortunately `supervisoryScope` is a suspending function  like `collect`